# Specifying spatial weight matrix for spatially lagged autoregressive model

Tags: r, autocorrelation, spatial, autoregressive

I'm trying to simulate data from a spatially lagged autoregressive model of the form y = ρWy + ϵ, where ρ is a spatial correlation parameter and W is a matrix of spatial weights based on an exponential decay function exp(-k * distance). The parameter k describes how rapidly the spatial weighting declines with distance (e.g. k = 0 indicates no decay with distance and k = 1 indicates very strong decay with distance).

I want to simulate data and then recover the true parameter values (using the spdep library in R, for example), but I'm finding that the spatial correlation parameter ρ tends to be underestimated when the exponential decay parameter k is relatively low. E.g.

```
# load spdep library
library(spdep)

# paramaters
N <- 200                          # sample size
rho <- 0.8                        # spatial correlation parameter
k <- rep(seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1), 4)   # exponential decay parameter

# generate spatial coordinates
set.seed(462)
dat <- data.frame(lat = runif(N, 0, 15), lon = runif(N, 0, 15))

# create distance matrix
dist <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(dat$lon, dat$lat), method = 'euclidean'))

# vector to store estimates of rho
rho_est <- vector()

# simulate data and fit lagsarlm model to estimate rho
for(i in 1:length(k)) {

  # spatial weight matrix
  wt <- exp(-k[i] * dist)
  diag(wt) <- 0

  # row-standardize spatial weights
  rs <- rowSums(wt)
  wt <- apply(wt, 2, function(x) x/rs)

  # simulate error values and y values
  e <- matrix(rnorm(N), ncol = 1)
  y <- invIrW(wt, rho = rho, method = 'solve', feasible = NULL) %*% e

  # fit model
  mod <- lagsarlm(y ~ 1, listw = mat2listw(wt, style = 'W'))
  rho_est[i] <- mod$rho
}

# plot estimates of rho versus exponential decay parameter k
plot(rho_est ~ k, xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(-2, 1), xlab = 'Exponential decay (k)')
abline(h = rho, lty = 2)     # true value of rho
```

[image: Rho versus exponential decay parameter]

This phenomenon doesn't seem to be limited to spatial weights based on an exponential decay... it also occurs for 'neighbourhood weight' models (i.e. the spatial weight is 1 for neighbours and 0 for non-neighbours). In this case, the larger the neighbourhood, the more likely it is that ρ is underestimated (and estimated with high variance). E.g.

```
# load spdep library
library(spdep)

# paramaters
N <- 200                          # sample size
rho <- 0.8                        # spatial correlation parameter
j <- rep(2:10, 4)                 # neibourhood size parameter

# generate spatial coordinates
set.seed(462)
dat <- data.frame(lat = runif(N, 0, 15), lon = runif(N, 0, 15))

# create distance matrix
dist <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(dat$lon, dat$lat), method = 'euclidean'))

# vector to store estimates of rho
rho_est <- vector()

# simulate data and fit lagsarlm model to estimate rho
for(i in 1:length(j)) {

  # spatial weight matrix
  wt = ifelse(dist <= j[i], 1, 0)
  diag(wt) = 0

  # row-standardize spatial weights
  rs <- rowSums(wt)
  wt <- apply(wt, 2, function(x) x/rs)

  # simulate error values and y values
  e <- matrix(rnorm(N), ncol = 1)
  y <- invIrW(wt, rho = rho, method = 'solve', feasible = NULL) %*% e

  # fit model
  mod <- lagsarlm(y ~ 1, listw = mat2listw(wt, style = 'W'))
  rho_est[i] <- mod$rho
}

# plot estimates of rho versus neibourhood size parameter j
plot(rho_est ~ j, ylim = c(-1, 1), xlab = 'Neibourhood size (j)')
abline(h = rho, lty = 2)     # true value of rho
```

[image: Rho versus neighbourhood size parameter]

I'm looking for help understanding why the estimation of the spatial correlation parameter ρ seems to depend on the nature of the weight matrix, as described above.